# Как сделать ссылку на телеграм?

Tags: html, telegram

Как сделать ссылку на телеграм?

пример:

```
<a href="https://t.me/Dimadv">Написать в Телеграм</a>
```

но если у человека нету никнейма, а просто номер?

Comment: Никак, через номер телефона это невозможно

Comment: https://telegram.org/blog/downloads-attachments-streaming/ru#ssilki-po-nomeru-telefona